# Swift WKWebView webViewDidClose(window.close()) not working

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView

after moving several pages, web do confirm action.

like this:

```
var Common = {
    Close : function (){
        if(confirm("confirm?")) window.close();
    }
}
```

in my code:

```
    webView.uiDelegate = self
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
        // this method is not invoked
        }
            
        func webViewDidClose(_ webView: WKWebView) {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
                    
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        // this method invoked
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: message, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert);
            
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel) {
                _ in completionHandler(false)
            }
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default) {
                _ in completionHandler(true)
            }
            
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

in my alertController I called completionHandler(true). but webViewDidClose is not invoked. so I can not dismiss web vc.

what is the problem?
What can I try?

Comment: Please provide more context. For example where are you calling the close from exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
// webView.load(URLRequest)
webView.evaluateJavaScript("window.open(\"\(url.absoluteString)\");", completionHandler: { result, error in
            
})

override func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
        if let currentWebView = createWebView {
            currentWebView.load(navigationAction.request)
            return nil
        }
                
        createWebView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
        
        createWebView!.navigationDelegate = self
        createWebView!.uiDelegate = self
        
        view.addSubview(createWebView!)
        
        return createWebView!
    }
```